# Resize dialog to take up more screen

Tags: android

I have a dialog that setContentView on a layout. I have an editText and Button in the layout set width to match parent but that makes it only as wide as the setTitle. As I enter info into the editText, the dialog expands with each character. Is it possible to make the dialog look like below without setting a dp size for the width of the items? Some system standard?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your XML that inflates the dialog layout? If you're not inflating via XML, my answer would be to do that with the root view width set to match_parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, a dialog being too small indicates that you're using `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content` (or `match_parent`).

You would think that `fill_parent` always ends up larger than `wrap_content`, but that's not the case with EditTexts.

Also, consider using `android:minEms` for your EditText.