# Narrow Dialog when starting new Activity in "Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge" mode

Tags: android, dialog, themes

I feel that I have tried anything to get my dialog fill about 75% (width) of the screen, when it starts. It was always looking great, but since I upgraded to Android 4.4 I cannot get my dialogs to look "normal" but instead they are very small.

When I open a dialog I use the Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge as the theme for an activity. All my dialogs are started as activities. I want them to be fullscreen on mobile devices and a dialog (popup) on tablets.

I tried the tips from the following post, but none seem to work:

- [Resize dialog to take up more screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570524/resize-dialog-to-take-up-more-screen)
- [Theme.Dialog creates too small screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969184/theme-dialog-creates-too-small-screen)
- [Custom dialog too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133822/custom-dialog-too-small)

This issue is driving me nuts... Any advice?

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code. Without seeing what you're doing, it's impossible to offer advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with me... ;-) It looks like that as soon as I post a question, I find a working solution:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   // In order to not be too narrow, set the window size based on the screen resolution:
   final int screen_width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
   final int new_window_width = screen_width * 75 / 100; 
   LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
   layout.width = Math.max(layout.width, new_window_width); 
   getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
}
```

I'm still not 100% happy with my solution, because I would like to avoid custom code to get the right screen size, but I guess I do have to work more on my layout. But for now, this solution is working for me.